moving multiple div Element with mouse
I have a code that can move a div object with the mouse.
let moverclass = { 
    __init: function () { 

      var elem = document.querySelector('.mover'), 
          div = document.querySelector('.move'),
          oldX = 0, 
          oldY = 0, 
          mousedown = false; 
 
      function start(e) { 
        mousedown = true; 
        var clientX = e.clientX || e.touches[0].clientX; 
        var clientY = e.clientY || e.touches[0].clientY; 
        oldX = clientX - div.offsetLeft; 
        oldY = clientY - div.offsetTop; 
      } 
       
      function end(e) { 
        mousedown = false; 
      } 
       
      function move(e) { 
        if (mousedown) { 
          var clientX = e.clientX || e.touches[0].clientX; 
          var clientY = e.clientY || e.touches[0].clientY; 
          var newX = clientX - oldX; 
          var newY = clientY - oldY; 
          if (newX >= 0 && newX <= (elem.offsetWidth - div.offsetWidth)) { 
            div.style.left = newX + 'px'; 
          } 
          if (newY >= 0 && newY <= (elem.offsetHeight - div.offsetHeight)) { 
            div.style.top = newY + 'px'; 
          } 
        } 
      } 
 
      div.addEventListener('mousedown', start, false); 
      div.addEventListener('touchstart', start, false); 
       
      window.addEventListener('mouseup', end, false); 
      window.addEventListener('touchend', end, false); 
       
      elem.addEventListener('
', move, false); 
      elem.addEventListener('touchmove', move, false); 
    }

  }; 
 
  moverclass.__init();

But I need several objects. I would like to be able to assign an image to each div later and thus create an individual image like a puzzle. The instructions for this are:

Select Elements: Select all the elements that you want to move, e.g., using document.querySelectorAll('.move').
Add Event Listeners: Add an event listener for mousedown, mouseup, and mousemove to each selected element.
Update Position: The position of each element is updated similarly as before but in a loop for each element.

After a lot of searching, it should look something like this:
document.querySelectorAll('.move').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('mousedown', event => {
    //handle function
  })
})

But I can't get it to work. Can anyone help?

please check http://javascriptisnotjava.com/  - I cannot see how this question is related to Java - it is also indicated to take the [tour]

Please edit the tags to use the right tag for the language you are actually using.

I changed the post and now the answers are gone? I am so stupid. What have I done?
The right answer was already there! That's exactly how I wanted it to be.

@ADITYA Thank you for your help. Everything is working as I wanted.
